# Adobe Target: Unable to load all site elements in the editor

Tags: javascript, html, adobe, response-headers

I'm in the process of migrating to Adobe Target for our A/B testing solution. I have Target successfully installed via Adobe Data Collection. However, not all the page elements load in the editor when I try to create test modifications. The missing components I've identified so far have been fonts, external CSS stylesheets, and forms with JavaScript functionality (a crucial component of our site for any sort of testing).

Here are some other relevant details:

- Our site is **not** on Adobe Experience Manager
- We use Firefox (have also tried in Chrome. Adobe recommends Firefox so we're sticking with that, but have still been testing in both)
- The form/JavaScript elements are hosted within the domain

I'm happy to provide other details anyone may deem relevant. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

We expected to see and be able to edit all site elements in the Target editor, but it won't load JavaScript and CSS components.

We originally thought the issue stemmed from a MIME type mismatch with our site's header "X-Content-Type-Options" being set to "nosniff": [nosniff error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w93S.png)

However, when we changed the header value to "sniff,"
we started getting 404 errors within the Target editor for all our site's JavaScript files: [404 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2TP3.png)

What else we've tried:

- We toggled the Target editor "Page Delivery" options ("render using JavaScript" and "enable Enhanced Composer), but this didn't change anything
- We tried to install an anti-flicker code snippet, but this didn't change anything